# How get custom error pages for kubernetes ingress-nginx with helm charts?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

So I am using the [nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and installed it trough the helm chart:

```
helm install --set controller.kind=DaemonSet --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/do-loadbalancer-size-slug"="lb-large" --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname"="some\.url\.com" ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

This automatically created a loadbalancer on digital ocean as well.

As far as I understand until now, referencing [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/custom-errors/) i have to:

1. Create a docker image which will act as default backend, like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/images/custom-error-pages).
2. Have to set the following things in the helm chart:

   - defaultBackend.enable => true
   - defaultBackend.image => The image created in step 1.
   - controller.config.custom-http-errors => [404, 503, ..] (all the errors i want to be handled by the default backend ([config values reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md)).
3. Upgrade the helm chart.

Would this be the right and also easiest approach or is there a simpler way?

Also would upgrading the helm chart, remove the old loadbalancer and create a new one?

Comment: Looks like that's exactly what https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/ says to do, have you tried your approach already?

Comment: No, i wanted to check if this really is the "simplest" way to do that and also I'm kind of concerned that the loadbalancer will be replaced, which would lead to a new IP for it.

Comment: Any progress in your case?

Comment: Sorry for not replying, it seams to work as far as i can tell. But I only was able to test it locally, because in production (as far as I can tell) upgrading the nginx-ingress helm chart, could cause the loadbalancer(-service | from the chart) to get upgraded again which in turn might create a new loadbalancer, which would have a new IP address, so we still have to find a solution to prevent this or at least so it would not have such ab big impact.

Comment: No problem, you can always use a --reuse-values command when upgrading helm chart which as per the --help: "when upgrading, reuse the last release's values and merge in any overrides from the command line via --set and -f. If '--reset-values' is specified, this is ignored". Also, you can use --dry-run flag which will show you what changes would happen due to the update.

Comment: Hi @natschz, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Hi @MikolajS. I did get it to work on my local environment, but for production we decided to postpone it.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to upgrade helm chart (what do you want to change etc.)? Did you try to do it already -"production (as far as I can tell) upgrading the nginx-ingress helm chart, could cause the loadbalancer(-service | from the chart)" ? If yes, in which way, what did you change? I tried to upgrade helm chart using `helm upgrade` command and the LoadBalancer IP stayed the same.

Comment: No until now we didn't try it, because we want to have a backup plan. I'm not sure it could be that nothing changes or maybe some variable we set will cause the loadbalancer service to get upgraded? It was more or less a question if and when that could happen. But its really good to know that for you it stayed the same!

Comment: Update: I just asked a coworker and he said he did upgrade it already and it seamd to stay the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be the right and also easiest approach or is there a simpler way?

The steps presented in the question based on [official NGINX Ingress Controller wiki](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/) are correct and seems to be easiest approach.

> Also would upgrading the helm chart, remove the old loadbalancer and create a new one?

After using command `helm upgrade` the LoadBalancer will stay the same - the IP address won't change.
By running `helm list` command you can see that upgrade took place, by checking `REVISION` and `UPDATED` fields.

```
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
ingress-nginx   default         4               2021-09-06 10:38:14.447456942 +0000 UTC deployed        ingress-nginx-3.35.0    0.48.1
```

Comment: Yea as I said before we posponed this for now, but in theory everything should work. I'm just not sure if I should accept this as correct answer since I'm not sure what happens if you change some values in the values.yaml which will set in the loadbalancer service. This might cause the loadbalancer to get updated? (I probably won't test this and everything beside that seams wo work so idk should i just accept this answer?)